# Flask Custom Routing

Tags: python, routes, flask

Say that I'm defining a user profile page in Flask:

```
@app.route('/user/<name>')
def user(name):
    do stuff
```

I'd like to change the routing rules so that I can put more than just one designation in the `<name>`, e.g. `<name, location>` to translate to the user with that name and location, url given by /user/James-Oregon.

Comment: Can you edit your question? I think you left out a few words in the description, and that's making it hard to understand what you're asking.

Comment: Ah, yes, thanks for pointing this out. I had forgotten a couple of code tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you're looking for...

```
@app.route('/user/<name>-<location>')
def user(name, location):
    # do stuff...
```

When using URL `/user/James-Oregon`, you should get "James" for `name` and "Oregon" for `location`.

Note that flask is largely built off of [Werkzeug](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/), so be sure to check out the [Werkzeug routing documentation](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/routing/) as well.

Comment: + 1 for the Werkzeug routing documentation